# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple, Issue happens in a parallel corpus

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

The following is my dataset. It is a parallel corpus.

[['Service eka godaak hondai', 'සේවාව  ගොඩාක් හොඳයි '],
['Kama rasai ', 'කෑම රසයි '],
['Godak fresh and maarama rasaii, perfect. ', 'ඉතා රසවත් හා ඉතා රසවත්, පරිපූර්ණයි'],
['place eka piliwelai, clean , kama godaak rasai', 'ස්ථානය පිළිවෙලට, පිරිසිදුයි, කෑම හරිම රසයි']]

when I try this following code

```
singlish_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:,0])
```

This error below is shown

---

```
   TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

  <ipython-input-138-74d68e010cad> in <module>

  3 # a[:stop]       # items from the beginning through stop-1

  4 #a[:]  means a copy of the whole array

  5 singlish_tokenizer = create_tokenizer(dataset[:,0])

  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

this is the **create_tokenizer method**

```
def create_tokenizer(lines):

   tokenizer = Tokenizer()

   tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lines)

   return tokenizer
```

Can anyone please help me in this issue. I tried different solutions but nothing worked. I am stuck with this code.